# Render in rails a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Sorry for a simple question but i am a bit confused trying to follow ruby on rails tutorial book

I am at the chapter 10 and confused, yes i trick a bit my version for learning purpose
So I have a controller called customer
customers_controller.rb

```
def show
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
    @posts = @customer.posts
end
```

I then have the following folder
_post.html.erb

```
Welcome to a post
```

Which his called from the show customer file has follow
/view/customer/show.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, @customer.name) %>
<aside class="customer_show_nav">
<h1><%= @customer.name %></h1>
<%= @customer.email %>
</aside>

<div class="events">
    <%= render @posts %>
</div>
```

But when loading nothing his appearing not even Welcome to a post. What i am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance. I am following the tutorial http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/user-microposts#top 10.22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `_post.html.erb` is in `view/customers`

you do this in `view/customers/show.html.erb`

`<%= render 'controller_where_post_lives/post' %>` which will look for `customers/_post.html.erb`

Sometimes, you also need `=` in `<%= %>` with rails 3

Also, show is used to show one item, and index is used to show all items.

So to render you will do

```
<%= render :partial => "post", :collection => @posts %>
```

**Edit:**

When you call render you give it the view, no objects here.  Unless like above passing a collection.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Also if you just want to render text you can do `render :text => "OK"`

Comment: posts lives in folder view/posts/_post.html.erb So I try the following render 
<%= render posts/@posts %>
<%= render posts/@post %>
<%= render @posts/@posts %>

but none work what else i am suppose to do?

Comment: Thank you, <%render 'posts/post' simply works, is it possible to render an index from an other controller?

Comment: just make the file name _index.html.erb then you can do the same

Answer (score 0):

Look for [partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) explanation.